# Remove Files completely from git repository along with its history

Tags: git, bitbucket, delete-file

I have uploaded a font file that I don't have the rights to distribute to git hub several updates ago.

I have a relatively inactive repository and I have the ability to notify all of my members if necessary. I've tried several of the solutions. I need to delete a file in my directory called `Resources\Video\%font%.ttf` where `%font%` is the name of the plain, italicized and bold versions of the font. What commands do I use?

Answer (score 152, accepted):

In that case you could to use [Git Filter Branch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) command with `--tree-filter` option.

syntax is `git filter-branch --tree-filter <command> ...`

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -f Resources\Video\%font%.ttf' -- --all
```

---

**Edit Updated**

Note that `git filter-branch` `--index-filter` is much faster than `--tree-filter`

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'rm -f Resources\Video\%font%.ttf' -- --all
```

---

> In windows had to use `/` instead of `\`.

---

*Explanation about the command:*

`< command >` Specify any shell command.

`--tree-filter:`Git will check each commit out into working directory, run your command, and re-commit.

`--index-filter:` Git updates git history and not the working directory.

`--all:` Filter all commits in all branches.

**Note:** Kindly check the path for your file as I'm not sure for the file path

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 62):

According to the official git docs, using `git filter-branch` [is strongly discouraged](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch#_warning), and the recommended approach is to use the contributed [git-filter-repo](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/) command.

[Install](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/main/INSTALL.md) it (via package, or with package python3-pip, do a [pip install](https://superuser.com/a/1589985/218514): `pip install git-filter-repo`).

The command to exorcise `filename` [is then](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/main/Documentation/converting-from-filter-branch.md#removing-a-file):

```
git filter-repo --invert-paths --path filename
```

The `--invert-paths` option indicates to exclude, not include the following paths.

Comment: `pip install git-filter-repo`

Comment: not a stock git command

Answer (score 24):

`git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch Resources\Video\%font%.ttf' HEAD` can be much (up to 100x) faster than `--tree-filter` because it only updates git history and not the working directory.

ref: [What is the difference between "--tree-filter" and "--index-filter" in the "git filter-branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36255221/what-is-the-difference-between-tree-filter-and-index-filter-in-the-git) 
ref: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch

Answer (score 0):

**Take backup**

###### Inside Working Directory

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch Resources\Video\%font%.ttf' --prune-empty --tag--name-filter cat -- --all 
git push origin --all --force
```

###### Inside Bare Repo

```
git gc --prune=now
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).