# What is the difference between "--tree-filter" and "--index-filter" in the "git filter-branch"?

Tags: git

I learn "tree" and "index" from the this aritcle: [Learning Git Internals by Example](http://teohm.com/blog/2011/05/30/learning-git-internals-by-example/)

but when it come to "git filter-branch" command, I don't know what is the difference between "--tree-filter" and "--index-filter".

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I do, but I find these Git concept is hard to understand...

Comment: One does not simply read the docs @TimBiegeleisen! There are badges to be gained! (Great name by the way ;) )

Answer (score 22):

The short version is that `--tree-filter` checks out each commit into a temporary directory, runs your filter command, and builds a new commit from whatever is now in the temporary directory; while `--index-filter` copies each commit into the index, runs your filter command, and builds a new commit from whatever is now in the index.

Copying a commit to the index is much<sup>1</sup> faster than checking out the commit.  Building a commit from the index is faster than building a commit from a directory.  As a result, using the index filter is much faster than using the tree filter.  It's not as easy to script for, though.

---

<sup>1</sup>The exact speed difference depends on your temporary directory: an in-memory file system is faster than an on-SSD file system which is faster than on-spinning-media, so you gain more if you're using spinning media than if you can point the tree filter to an in-memory file system.  But even then the index filter is still faster.

On actual disks, I've seen about a factor of 100 or so (hence an index filter that takes 2 minutes translates to a tree filter that takes 3+ hours).

Comment: Amazing extra research there @torek, can't learn this stuff by just reading the docs!

Comment: @timhc22: I'm approximating from some historical values here. I did a lot of repository surgery back in the mid-200x or early 201x-es. Had to use real spinning media for a while, then had a ramdisk file system to use for some of it later...