# How to remove file from Git history?

Tags: git, github

Some time ago I added info(files) that must be private. Removing from the project is not problem, but I also need to remove it from `git` history.

I use Git and Github (private account).

Note: On [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307828/completely-remove-file-from-all-git-repository-commit-history)  something similar is shown, but here is an old file that was added to a feature branch, that branch merged to a development branch and finally merged to master, since this, a lot of changes was done. So it's not the same and what is needed is to change the history, and hide that files for privacy.

Comment: You would have to rewrite history. For example `git rebase` then `git push -f`

Comment: The `filter-branch` method described in the suggested duplicate will do what you want.

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/a/17890278/ which points to the [BFG](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) which can be faster than using `git filter-branch`

Comment: but just go faster and do the same, and need to use java i read @Hasturkun

Comment: NONE of theses solutions worked... GIT should have a command for this... it's so useful...

Comment: I found I just needed to check the last 20 commits so adding `HEAD~20..HEAD` was helpful for me to know.

Comment: @MarcosR.Guevara Would you mind changing the accepted answer to one that's up to date? git filter-branch is no longer recommended.

Answer (score 524, accepted):

I have found this answer and it helped:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch path_to_file' HEAD
```

Comment: Warning: This creates a ton of commits and causes divergence. You probably have to force push after, but I was too scared.

Comment: Seconding what @sudo said but this did work for my fresh branch that I accidentally committed `.env` to. 

Quick and to the point solution.

Comment: Indeed, a simple force push works! I was also scared but backed everything up.

Comment: You can also specify a range of commits as the last argument. If the commit in question was recent, do `<previous_hash>..HEAD` and save some time.

Comment: after this it works only for me `git push --force`

Comment: You could see this command [in Git's manpage](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch#_exampleshttps://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch#_examples) also, which provides other examples, and some important notes as well.

Comment: Didn't work, and the commits i made are now on the revision history... tried many approaches...

Comment: @marcolopes I guess you did something wrong, you also have to consider doing `git push --force`

Comment: I did everything just like the examples here and in other sources... and i did the git push --force. Tried many times. No success! File is still there and still in the revision history... :\ Now i have a huge history for that file.

Comment: One of those commands you don't understand but it works wonders !

Comment: This did not remove the file from my repo, it remains  as it is

Comment: Current versions of Git say this about `filter-branch`: "WARNING: git-filter-branch has a glut of gotchas generating mangled history rewrites.  Hit Ctrl-C before proceeding to abort, then use an alternative filtering tool such as 'git filter-repo' (https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/) instead.  See the filter-branch manual page for more details; to squelch this warning, set FILTER_BRANCH_SQUELCH_WARNING=1."

Comment: @sudo It did not add even a single commit for me and worked perfectly fine. What are you talking about? A ton of commits?! What am I missing?

Comment: @aderchox it doesn't exactly "add" commits, it rewrites existing ones. Those commits get replaced by new ones, with a different hash number

Comment: Even @sudo was scared, and there's a good reason for it. Had to merge a branch into `main`/`master` by following https://stackoverflow.com/a/4624383/929999 after this. I guess it does the job but as the warning says, do it at your own risk :)

Comment: if anyone doing this, it is major operation but does seem to work, just also know after operation have to do git push origin --force --all on main and before that probably in github have to allow forced pushes on that branch would would normally be protected.  then have all engs rebase main.  Seems it closes all outstanding PRs also.

Comment: This doesn't really remove the file from the remote, right?  Best-case it will get garbage-collected at some point...  Is there a more thorough method if you have access to the remote itself?

Comment: this worked for my single master branch.

Comment: I had to add `--force` after `filter-branch` before anything worked. Also added `HEAD~2..HEAD` so it only did the last 2 commits where the change was made and not every commit.

Comment: @sudo you can create a bogus branch to test it. It's definitely not scary.

Comment: `fatal: ambiguous argument 'rm': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.`

Answer (score 234):

### git-filter-repo

`git` recommends using the third-party add-on [git-filter-repo](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) (when `git filter-branch` command is executed). There is a [long list of reasons why `git-filter-repo` is better than any other alternatives](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo#why-filter-repo-instead-of-other-alternatives), my experience is that it is very simple and very fast.

This command removes the file from all commits in all branches:

```
git filter-repo --invert-paths --path <path to the file or directory>
```

Multiple paths can be specified by using multiple `--path` parameters. You can find detailed documentation here:
https://www.mankier.com/1/git-filter-repo

Comment: i get error: git: 'filter-repo' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Comment: @cikatomo It's a third-party tool, you have to install it https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/main/INSTALL.md

Comment: This was the answer that helped me with the simple case of removing a couple of specific files from a repo.

Comment: This worked but it removed `.git` so I wonder why not just remove .`git` manually and re-init?

Comment: to install on arch use `yay -S git-filter-repo`

Comment: This should be set as the new best answer as it is more up-to-date.

Comment: note: paths are relative to the repo root

Comment: @cikatomo Another way to install `pip install git-filter-repo`.

Comment: @KaushalModi if I installed the plugin with `pip`, what then next?

Comment: @Timo The pip install would have installed the `git-filter-repo` executable. Just ensure that it's in the PATH. Then `git filter-repo ..` will work.

Comment: how to also update remote repo after this?

Comment: @João Pimentel Ferreira You must force push into the remote. Be careful with force push, only do it if you know that this is that you want to :)

Comment: if you are having trouble installing git-filter-repo check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69356543/713847

Comment: this re-wrote the entire history. When I pushed my branch to origin, it's completely diverged from the rest of the git history. It would work if I pushed all branches to origin, but I don't want to do that.

Comment: @MuhsinFatih Of course, this is how git works: when some files are removed from the commit, this is an entirely new commit. There is no other way to remove files from the git repo than rewriting the history. (This is not specific for this solution.)

Comment: @TiborTakács I meant that I imagined it will only diverge from the first occurrence of the file, but the entire history of all branches was re-written. I think that this may not be practical if the changes are already pushed to remote. I ended up cherry picking the commits where I pushed the offending file

Comment: @chovy to keep all of your commit history

Comment: And as @chovy points out, this seems to break non-bare clones (you get a warning if its not bare and you `--force` it). You need to add the remote again afterwards to push your branch. In my case anyway.

Comment: **Be very careful** with this tool. I almost lost a lot of work. Read the docs and consider backing up all your files to a zip file outside of the directory before proceeding. The tool is bad about not giving you enough warning. It's very much an RTFM situation.

Comment: Citation?
Where is it written "git recommends using the third-party add-on git-filter-repo"?

Comment: @KimTaylor https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch#_warning citing: "These safety and performance issues cannot be backward compatibly fixed and as such, its use is not recommended. Please use an alternative history filtering tool such as git filter-repo."

Comment: Installed this package with: sudo apt  install git-filter-repo

Comment: to install on mac: `brew install git-filter-repo`

Answer (score 171):

If you have recently committed that file, or if that file has changed in one or two commits, then I'd suggest you use `rebase` and `cherrypick` to remove that particular commit.

Otherwise, you'd have to rewrite the entire history.

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -f <path_to_file>' HEAD
```

When you are satisfied with the changes and have duly ensured that everything seems fine, you need to update all remote branches -

```
git push origin --force --all
```

*Note:- It's a complex operation, and you must be aware of what you are doing. First try doing it on a demo repository to see how it works. You also need to let other developers know about it, such that they don't make any change in the mean time.*

Comment: after rewrite the entire history, for keep the changes to repository (github) what must be done?

Comment: thank you, i will wait for do it, and try it with a demo repository, i will update with all was done here.

Comment: By mistake, I forgot to add `--all`. Now it says everything up-to-date whenever I rerun push with both the arguments. And the file is not removed from other branches. What should I do now?

Comment: Why does your suggestion use `--tree-filter` rather than `--index-filter` like in @PetroFranko's answer?

Comment: holy crap, it worked!  I mean it was really really simple.  I've done it the hard way before, but this was much easier.  Tip:  the path needs to be relative.

Comment: Didn't work :\ File is still on local repo and after "git push" still on the git remote repository, and the revisions are all there! :\

Comment: @einpoklum basically, `tree-filter` rebuilds everything to (and then from) a new (temporary) directory. `index-filter` does this differently (in memory I believe) and is considerably faster. See more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36255221/what-is-the-difference-between-tree-filter-and-index-filter-in-the-git

Comment: It does not seems to be working for me. Doing the same command exactly mentioned here but still I can see the files in remote repo. Anything I am missing here?

Comment: i still see it in history

Comment: The `git filter-branch` way would require action by all users of the repository, wouldn't it?

Comment: If ```Cannot create a new backup.
A previous backup already exists in refs/original/
Force overwriting the backup with -f``` you can remove backup with ```rm -rf .git/refs/original/refs/heads/``` also for removing multiple files at one express files full path as rm arguments. For example: ```git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -f .gitignore out.csv' HEAD```

Comment: `WARNING: git-filter-branch has a glut of gotchas generating mangled history
  rewrites.  Hit Ctrl-C before proceeding to abort, then use an
  alternative filtering tool such as 'git filter-repo'
  (https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/) instead.  See the
  filter-branch manual page for more details; to squelch this warning,
  set FILTER_BRANCH_SQUELCH_WARNING=1.`

Answer (score 68):

Remove the file and rewrite history from the commit you done with the removed file(this will create new commit hash from the file you commited):

there are two ways:

1. Using [git-filter-branch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch):

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch <path to the file or directory>' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

2. Using [git-filter-repo](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo):

```bash
pip3 install git-filter-repo
git filter-repo --path <path to the file or directory> --invert-paths
```

---

now force push the repo: `git push origin --force --all` and tell your collaborators to `rebase`.

Comment: @alper you need to replace `PATH-TO-YOUR-FILE-WITH-SENSITIVE-DATA` with the file to remove eg: `README.md` if you want to remove it.

Comment: You need to use `-rf` in order to remove folders

Comment: For `git filter-repo`: I am getting following message : `Aborting: Refusing to destructively overwrite repo history since
this does not look like a fresh clone.
  (expected freshly packed repo)
Please operate on a fresh clone instead.  If you want to proceed
anyway, use --force.`. If I force it I get following: `fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
`

Comment: `git filter-branch` worked for me!

Comment: `git filter-branch` approach worked for me on mac, while `filter-repo` approach was removing remote origin

Comment: This worked, but I forgot to back up the file first, and now it's gone. :-(

Comment: I have the same problem of @IlyaSheershoff, filter-repo remove remote origin, anyone know why?

Comment: @RichardAguirre according to the developer doing that was "great design" -- they have reasons for doing that and the reasons are good ones https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/issues/46

Comment: You can specify file path like: "*/a.txt" if you happen to have the same file in different paths or files' path have changed in different commits.

Answer (score 50):

I read [this GitHub article](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository), which led me to the following command (similar to the accepted answer, but a bit more robust):

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter "git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch PATH-TO-YOUR-FILE-WITH-SENSITIVE-DATA" --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

Comment: It works better than accepted answer but It also deletes file in locale. Take copy of it before this if you don't want to waste time for rewrite.

Comment: this helped me on mac, while filter-repo was removing remote origin

Comment: my local file didn't get removed maybe because it was entered in .gitignore

Comment: don't forget the "git push --force" after all your purging is done.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks. I also added `-r` in case of deleting a directory

Answer (score 16):

- First of all, add it to your `.gitignore` file and don't forget to commit the file :-)
- You can use this site: http://gitignore.io to generate the `.gitignore` for you and add the required path to your binary files/folder(s)
- Once you added the file to `.gitignore` you can remove the "old" binary file with BFG.

---

## ***`How to remove big files from the repository`***

You can use `git filter-branch` or BFG.
https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/

> #### `BFG Repo-Cleaner`
>
> an alternative to git-filter-branch.

> The BFG is a simpler, faster alternative to git-filter-branch for cleansing **bad data** out of your Git repository history:

> *** Removing Crazy Big Files***
>
> - Removing Passwords, Credentials & other Private data

#### Examples (from the official site)

> In all these examples bfg is an alias for java -jar bfg.jar.

```
# Delete all files named 'id_rsa' or 'id_dsa' :
bfg --delete-files id_{dsa,rsa}  my-repo.git
```

[image]

Comment: Is it a third party cleaner?

Comment: Is it secure to use?

Comment: Indeed, a very "old" tool which is being used by the community for few years. The source is in GitHub so you and the community can browse it.

Comment: I just find out that GitHub does not remove deleted commits in case when users request them to run garbage collector, (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582480/remove-commit-for-good/34594815#34594815). I am just get lost where when we use 3rd party tools like GitHub whatever committed, we will always need to ask them to remove  it, which is not cool

Answer (score 11):

Using the [bfg repo-cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) package is another viable alternative to `git-filter-branch`. Apparently, it is also faster...

Answer (score 3):

Remove file(s)

```
bfg --delete-files YOUR-FILE-WITH-SENSITIVE-DATA
```

Replace all text listed in passwords.txt wherever it can be found in your repository's history, run:

```
bfg --replace-text passwords.txt
```

After that you need topush your changes to GitHub/GitLab/BitBucket

```
git push --force
```

More about the [BFG tool here](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/)

Furthermore, since this technique it will rewrite your repository's history, which changes the SHAs for existing commits, you should alter and any dependent commits. So merge and close all open PRs!

Answer (score 2):

**The following commands should be applied one by one in each project in order to remove the history for a specific file, but you have to take backup from the project at the beginning, because the file will be deleted**

- git filter-branch --index-filter "git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch
  **ProjectFolderName**/src/main/resources/**application-prod.properties**" HEAD
- git push origin --force --all
- git update-ref -d refs/original/refs/heads/master

..........................................................................

- git filter-branch --index-filter "git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch
  **ProjectFolderName**/src/main/resources/**application.properties**" HEAD
- git push origin --force --all
- git update-ref -d refs/original/refs/heads/master

Answer (score 0):

Add the file pattern to your .gitignore. Example:

`*.env`

Then remove the cached file information using this command(zsh):

`bash -c 'git rm --cached *.env'`