# Unable to exclude Pipfile and Pipfile.lock through .gitignore

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, github

I am trying to exclude Pipfile and Pipfile.lock by adding two lines in my .gitignore file. But they are not being omitted when they are pushed to git. Can someone please let me know why.

My .gitignore looks like this

```
Pipfile
Pipfile.lock
```

Comment: No idea but are you sure you want to exclude your Pipfile?

Comment: Actually, have you staged your `.gitignore` file?

Comment: I am using a GitHub desktop app to push all commits . I added a . gitignore just to see if it will exclude pip files. The .gitignore is there in the GitHub repository, but it didn't exclude the two files mentioned in it

Answer (score 1):

.gitignore has no effect whatsoever on what will be pushed. What will be pushed is whatever is *on the revisions* you are pushing. So if the files are already part of some of those revisions (in other words, they are already tracked), adding lines in .girignore won't make a difference. If you want them to be gone from those revisions then you will have to rewrite history. [How to remove file from Git history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43762338/how-to-remove-file-from-git-history)

Comment: Thanks very much, I got the reason now