# Git: How to deactivate history for a specific subfolder?

Tags: git, github

### 1. Description of the problem

Suppose I have the following project **foo**:

[image]

Project **foo** is cloned from a GitHub repository I own, and checked out to the master branch. Subfolders **bar** and **baz** contain pure source code. Subfolder **tools** contains some software that I need to run the project.

From time to time, I delete software in the **tools** folder to replace them with newer versions. Git keeps the history of everything that ever existed in the **tools** folder. That is absolutely not necessary.

### 2. Questions

I've got two questions:

1. Is it possible to delete the entire history of subfolder **tools**, without touching the history of **bar** and **baz**? The entire history of **tools** should be wiped out from my local `.git` repo and the remote GitHub repo once I push. When my coworkers pull, their local history of **tools** should be wiped out as well.
2. Is it possible to - starting from today - make Git stop keeping history for the **tools** folder? For example: I replace `tool_x_v1.0` with `tool_x_v1.1`, commit and push to GitHub. My coworkers pull from GitHub and should receive `tool_x_v1.1`. All traces of the old `tool_x_v1.0` should be wiped out from the remote GitHub repo and all local `.git` repos.
   <sup>Note: We also assume that `tool_x_v1.1` is perfectly backwards compatible with `tool_x_v1.0`.</sup>

### 3. Side effects

Now you may wonder:

*What happens when I checkout an old commit - let's say a commit from 5 Nov 2018. The **tools** subfolder has no history dating back to that moment (its entire history is gone). What will it contain?*

Subfolder **tools** should simply contain the current contents - no matter what old commit you're checking out. I would even go further: no matter what branch you're checking out. The **tools** folder has no history and is branch-agnostic. As simple as that.

### 4. Criticism

Some of you will think:

*Just don't use Git for this **tools** subfolder (put it in `.gitignore`). Use something else to synchronize this particular subfolder with your coworkers.*

That's indeed possible. But anyone who clones the git repo from GitHub will be unhappy when he/she realizes the project doesn't work. He/She will need to download the **tools** folder from some other source, and possible need to install some third-party software to keep it up-to-date. Very cumbersome, don't you think?

> If you disagree - just ignore me and live happily ever after. Please don't go ranting in the comments, telling me how evil I am desecrating the noble Git.

Answer (score 1):

Question 1: yes. Use [bfg](https://github.com/rtyley/bfg-repo-cleaner) or [`git filter-branch`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43762338/how-to-remove-file-from-git-history) to remove just that subfolder, then add it to `.gitignore`. Note: this won't automatically remove other users' folders, thankfully, since in that case it would be possible to remove data from someone's repo using a pull request.

Question 2: You want git to record version changes without recording history? This isn't possible without a *lot* of `push -f` and `reset --hard` for all users. [git lfs](https://git-lfs.github.com/) will stop git from keeping software versions as binary diffs, but can't handle this automatic updating without versioning you want. Perhaps a synced dropbox folder is closer what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you @alan ocallaghan. You gave me some stuff to think about :-)