# Gitignore does not ignore folder android, react native

Tags: android, git, react-native, gitignore

I have added folder android to `.gitingore` file, executing the following commands:

```
git rm -rf --cached . 
git add .
git commit -m "git"
git push origin master
```

Folder android anyway tries to push, it's has large files and git throws error that there are files > 100 mb.

I noticed this error on MacBook, when working on my react-native project.

here's my gitignore

```
.expo/*
npm-debug.*
*.jks
*.p8
*.p12
*.key
*.mobileprovision
android/
*.orig.*
web-build/
android/
web-report/
# macOS
.DS_Store
```

Comment: What is the output of your `git status`? is the folder in your files list? and use this .gitignore - http://gitignore.io/api/android

Comment: On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

 .editorconfig
 .eslintrc.js
 .expo-shared/
 .gitignore
 .prettierrc
 .watchmanconfig
 App.js
 app.json
 assets/
 babel.config.js
 index.js
 ios/
 package-lock.json
 package.json
 src/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `.gitignore` file seems correct to exclude the android folder.

Maybe you have committed a large file before editing the gitignore ? if yes you can take a look on how to [remove the large files from the Git History](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43762338/how-to-remove-file-from-git-history)

Comment: He removed those files with `git rm -rf --cached . `.