# git filter-branch doesn't delete all files i want

Tags: git

I'm trying to clean up a git repository of latex code that contains the generated pdf files, because these files have caused the repo to balloon up to a size of 300mb.

Adapting a bit from the answer here [How to remove file from Git history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43762338/how-to-remove-file-from-git-history). I tried the following command:

`git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch *.pdf' HEAD`

This reduced the size a little, but not as much as i'd hoped. When I then try the script found in the answer to this question: [How to find/identify large commits in git history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10622179/how-to-find-identify-large-commits-in-git-history), to find which files contribute to the size, it still shows several pdf files. However, if i try the script found in this question: [Which commit has this blob?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223678/which-commit-has-this-blob), it cannot find any commit that contains the file.

I have removed all branches except the local branch. I have not pushed the changes to the remote.

Is there any reason these files would still persist in the history somewhere? What other things can I try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have blobs still present just because the garbage collector didn't collect them.

Try cloning your local repo, and check the size of the `.git/` directory in that new clone :

```
git clone myrepodir myclone
cd myclone
du -sh .git

# you can then remove that clone :
cd ..
rm -rf myclone
```

This will be a more acurate view of how much data would be pushed or cloned.

---

If you are 100% positive the content after your `filter-branch` action is the content you want to keep, and if you don't mind loosing your reflog (no more undos, drops all your stashes) : you can run

```
git gc --aggressive --prune=now
```

See also `git help gc` for more details on what could be retained on your disk.

Comment: Shouldn't `file://./myrepodir` be used so that a real transfer of the reachable objects takes place? Otherwise, packfiles could be copied or hard-linked and unwanted objects could end up in the clone.

Comment: the clone ended up pretty much the same size as the original repo, but the garbage collection really helped.

Comment: @j6t : you're right, I had forgotten about that optimization