# What happens with the file in the git log after you remove it from index and directory

Tags: git

What happens with the file in git log after you remove the file from index and git directory using git rm ?
I tried to remove a file using git rm  and then searched for it in git log and it still gave me all the commits for this specific file.

**Answer:**

Like @mkrieger1 said the file is with git rm removed from the repository but all the history regarding this removed file is still in the git log. Of course there is a possibility of rewriting history like @evolutionxbox suggested. Thanks to both :)

Comment: As you have seen, nothing happens to the file in `git log` when you use `git rm`. It doesn't change the existing commits.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove file from Git history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43762338/how-to-remove-file-from-git-history)

Answer (score 0):

Like @mkrieger1 said the file is with git rm removed from the repository but all the history regarding this removed file is still in the git log. Of course there is a possibility of rewriting history like @evolutionxbox suggested. Thanks to both :)