# git re-write history by squashing as many commits as possible by the same user

Tags: git

I have git repo with 50k files. I want to make a new version of this repo that

1. Has only 5k files
2. Keeps only the commit history of those 5k files.
3. For one user (me), squashes their commits to as few as possible

For 1 and 2 I believe there are already answers on S.O. For example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43762338/how-to-remove-file-from-git-history/43762489)

For 3, I can't imagine any trivial way to do it. It seems like I'd want to squash every commit by me until some commit by someone else touches a file I touched since my last commit. Is there a command combination to do that or would I have to write some script to figure it out?

In other words. There are files A, B, C,

- commit 1: I edit A
- commit 2: I edit B
- commit 3: Other user edits C
- commit 4: I edit A
- commit 5: I edit C
- commit 6: Other user edits C

At this point 1, 2, 4, 5 can be squished so the new history would be

- commit 1: Other user edits C
- commit 2: I edit A, B, A, C
- commit 3: Other user edits C

Comment: I think you'll need to write a script.

Comment: This can get complicated pretty quickly. E.g. what if commit 6 was "Other user deletes C", then the optimal post-squash sequence would become simply "commit 1: I edit A, B, A". And we haven't even got to merges yet. :)

Comment: Yea, I know. Even a non-optimal solution (squash consecutive commits by me) would be useful if it's simple to do. I might be able to do that with an interactive rebase by doing some regexs to replace pick with squash if the same user appears on consecutive lines.

Comment: My gut feeling would be to go with the concept in your last comment- don't re-order any commits.

Comment: Just curious- what's the reason for #3?