# how to ignore .next folder in nextjs project?

Tags: reactjs, git, next.js, frontend, gitignore

When I change anything in my project and save it,
it always shows some changes in `.next` folder. I know this is something issue in `.gitignore`,
but how can i fix it?

[image]

Comment: [The same way](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) you ignore any other file or directory.

Comment: I already add ./next in .gitignore file, but still same issue.

Comment: .next folder is used o be created while you build or run your project

Comment: See question linked as duplicate : run `git rm -r --cached .next/` followed by `git commit`. If you additionally want to remove this directory from all past commits, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64563565/86072)

Comment: can you please share your gitignore?

Comment: hi @TalhaFayyaz, this my git ignore file.



# See https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/ for more about ignoring files.

# dependencies
/node_modules
/.pnp
.pnp.js

# testing
/coverage

# next.js
/.next/
/out/

# production
/build

# misc
.DS_Store
*.pem

# debug
npm-debug.log*
yarn-debug.log*
yarn-error.log*
.pnpm-debug.log*

# local env files
.env*.local

# vercel
.vercel

Comment: i think simply doing .next would be enough no need to put / in front of it.

Comment: no @TalhaFayyaz, I tried but not worked

Comment: you have to also remove it from your git remote if it is already commited.