# Trouble with large file and git commit

Tags: git

I have a git repo and I took these steps:

1. Create files 1, 2, 3
2. Commit files 1, 2, 3
3. Push files 1, 2, 3 to remote
4. Add a too-large file (file 4)
5. Modify file 1
6. Commit 1 and 4
7. Modify file 2
8. Commit 2
9. Further changes to files 1, 2, 3, with commits
10. Push to remote
11. Push fails with "/path/file 4 exceeds GitHub's file size limit"

I tried deleting the large file locally and adding it to my gitignore, but I remain unable to push.

I also tried:

- git reset --soft HEAD^
- git rm --cached '/path/file 4'
- git restore --staged .
- git stash & git rebase master

The rm command gave me an error because the path did not match any files. The result of the rest of the commands is that `git status` shows:

```
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 6 commits.
```

I do not need the large file in the repo and I have a backup of the files I changed (1, 2, and 3). What is my best option for getting back to a state where I can push my commits?

Edit:
I had a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43762338/how-to-remove-file-from-git-history) and it doesn't seem to match my question because the original poster of that question says, "Removing from the project is not problem..." but that seems to be exactly what my problem is. No matter what I do, my branch remains six commits ahead of origin/master.

Comment: Have you considered using `git filter-branch` to remove the too-large file from your history retroactively? (See also https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository -- that FAQ is written for things you didn't want up because they're sensitive, but taking down things you don't want up because of their size is really the same thing)

Comment: ...and because those _are_ the same thing, arguably [How to remove file from git history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43762338/how-to-remove-file-from-git-history) is a duplicate of this question

Comment: The Github doc to which you linked mentions using Brew to install git filter-repo. Running on Windows, I have no idea what Brew is so I stopped looking at it there. The other link you mentioned says to run git filter-branch, which I did. After a couple of minutes, I got back `WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/master' is unchanged` and origin/master remains 6 commits behind by branch.

Comment: A question about a specific problem running `git filter-branch` is likely to be on-topic here. Be sure you provide enough details about _exactly_ what you did to let someone reproduce the problem themselves.

Comment: That said, Googling "install git filter-repo on Windows" [does find results](https://jessehouwing.net/installing-git-filter-repo-on-windows/), so an answer having MacOS-specific install instructions shouldn't prevent you from getting past that step on your own and proceeding with usage notes.

Comment: (It doesn't matter if the author of the other question says "removing it from the project is not my problem" -- what they mean by "from the project" is from the _current_ state, whereas the question is about _historical_ state; here, you can't push your project to github because the _historical_ state contains something too large for github to receive -- so it really is the same problem, whether or not they choose to be picky about words in a way that doesn't really matter).