Git "GH001: Large files detected." hell
I cannot push to remote due to this error

remote: error: Trace: c2b7d3a65e1846eb15fbadeffded0c85fcfd8786d1946da44c644e3aa49eb6df
remote: error: See https://gh.io/lfs for more information.
remote: error: File google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb is 151.89 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
To https://github.com/**-Dev/**-services.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/-Dev/-services.git'

What i did

I removed the large files that were committed previously in github gui (they no longer exist in cloud
removed them from local large files and pulled from cloud
I ran git rm google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb but i got this fatal: pathspec 'google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb' did not match any files

But i still cannot push without seeing the original error. The large files are not in the cloud not on my local directory nor are they in a commit on local.

If the large files were once Git's history, deleting them in a recent commit will not solve this. You need to rewrite history to remove them from old commits. More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43762338/how-to-remove-file-from-git-history
